# Double center text issue in TextView and RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've a problem centering a text in an already centered TextView:

That's the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout>... 
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/w0"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:background="@color/green1"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/temperature"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    android:text="15º"
    android:textSize="60dip"
    style="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
    android:background="@color/green1"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/min_temperature"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/temperature"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/temperature"
    android:text="M 21º"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    style="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:background="@color/orange1"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/max_temperature"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/temperature"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/temperature"
    android:text="m 10º"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    style="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:background="@color/orange2"
    />
```

And that's the displayed layout image:

[image: Layout image]

What I don't understand is why the 15º isn't centered in the TextView.
The problem is due the TextView's forced center using alignTop and alignBottom but I can't see why it doesn't works.
I know I can solve this using some nesting layouts but I prefer to get a solution using only the RelativeLayout or if it isn't possible understand the reason.

Also is there a solution to align the maximum and minimum TextViews with the top and bottom of the 15º text (not the TextView) as there is now.

Comment: Have you used hierarchyinspector to check the layout attributes, size, etc. of the TextView? (It's interesting that the text in the two orange TextViews seem to be vertically centered in their backgrounds.)

Comment: er...that's `hierarchyviewer`, not `hierarchyinspector`.

Comment: Thank you Ted. I've tried but it doesn't seems to work with my application. I've opened another question about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505538/error-loading-activity-with-hierarchyviewer

Answer (score 0):

> Also is there a solution to align the maximum and minimum TextViews with the top and bottom of the 15º text (not the TextView) as there is now.

- I don't think so. You can only make things relative to the actual box that the View represents. And in the case of TextView the box is larger than the Text. Any relations that you do make are going to use the position of the Box no matter where the text is at or what it looks like.

Try using

android:layout_centerVertical="true"

on your temperature TextView in addition to the gravity you have now.

Comment: I can't use it because in reality the RelativeLayout is bigger and the  ImageView has a layout_below relationship that I've omitted for brevity.

Comment: The `android:gravity` attribute for a TextView is supposed to control the vertical and horizontal placement of the text within the box occupied by the view. OP's question is, why is `android:gravity="center"` not working to center the text vertically in the green background.