# Error loading activity with HierarchyViewer

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried to inspect a layout using HierarchyViewer but it doesn't load.
Firstly I've tried with an emulator and as it wasn't working then I've tried using the [ViewServer](https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer)

With emulator it failed silently but with ViewServer I'm able to get an stacktrace:

```
W/dalvikvm(459): Unable to match class for part: 'Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;)V'
 W/View(459): Problem dumping the view:
 W/View(459): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
 W/View(459):   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Native Method)
 W/View(459):   at java.lang.ClassCache.getDeclaredMethods(ClassCache.java:140)
 W/View(459):   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:757)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.getExportedPropertyMethods(ViewDebug.java:1331)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.exportMethods(ViewDebug.java:1372)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:1364)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:1354)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewWithProperties(ViewDebug.java:1270)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchyWithProperties(ViewDebug.java:1244)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchyWithProperties(ViewDebug.java:1252)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchyWithProperties(ViewDebug.java:1252)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchyWithProperties(ViewDebug.java:1252)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchyWithProperties(ViewDebug.java:1252)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchyWithProperties(ViewDebug.java:1252)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchyWithProperties(ViewDebug.java:1252)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchyWithProperties(ViewDebug.java:1252)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.dump(ViewDebug.java:1204)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewDebug.dispatchCommand(ViewDebug.java:863)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.ViewRoot$W.executeCommand(ViewRoot.java:3070)
 W/View(459):   at android.view.IWindow$Stub.onTransact(IWindow.java:65)
 W/View(459):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
 W/View(459):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Any ideas of what can happening? I don't know if it's relevant but the application runs on ICS device and uses support library with SherlockBar

Comment: It might be that you are using api calls that are not supported on the device/emulator. One way to check this is to set the project API lavel to something no higher than that of the emulator or device.

Comment: In emulator can be but in the device it's targeted ICS and in both cases the application works correctly